# Pass class to another method

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I am calling a method called SimpleCriteria and passing Employees class

```
   empDAOImpl.SimpleCriteria(getEntityManager(),Employee.class);
```

In SimpleCriteria method How I would be able to use Employee class? I have tried as classEntity, but this didn't help.
       What is the correct manner of passing class to another method?

```
   public void SimpleCriteria(EntityManager entityManager, Class<T>
   classEntity)throws InstantiationException,IllegalAccessException{

   CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
   CriteriaQuery<classEntity> criteriaQuery = 
   criteriaBuilder.createQuery(classEntity);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need  generic. You can simply use classEntity as below

```
public void SimpleCriteria(EntityManager entityManager, Class
            classEntity)throws InstantiationException,IllegalAccessException {

        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery =
                criteriaBuilder.createQuery(classEntity);
    }
```

You need generic if you are returning CriteriaQuery like below

```
public <T> CriteriaQuery<T> SimpleCriteria(EntityManager entityManager, Class<T>
        classEntity)throws InstantiationException,IllegalAccessException {

    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    return criteriaBuilder.createQuery(classEntity);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this approach.